# Chain comes off under high load

Tags: chain

When I ride up a particularly steep hill my chain nearly always comes off. It didn't used to do this but now happens practically every time. I presume something has either worn or come out of alignment. It's fine in normal riding, but can't seem to handle this more extreme situation.

What is it most likely to be?

- Chain wear?
- Chainring wear?
- Front Derailleur issue?

Comment: I guessing you mean the chain comes off of the front sprockets. Presumably you are in (or shifting to) the largest sprocket at the rear and smallest ring at the front when this happens and the chain comes off the inner side of the chainrings. Does it happen while you are changing gear? Can you hear the front derailleur rubbing the chain?

Comment: You need to describe the problem better.  Does the chain come off the front or back?  Which way does it "leap"?  How many cogs do you have on the front and how many on the rear?  Which cogs are you typically using when this happens?  How many miles do you estimate are on chain and cogs?

Comment: Yes, the chain comes off the front sprockets on the inside. Shifting gear will cause it but it also happens even if I am not shifting gear. I would be in the smaller (of two) chain ring and one of the largest sprockets at the back (11 speed).

Comment: It sounds like the low limit on the front derailer needs tweaking.

Answer (score 5):

I would look for a bent or damaged chainring tooth or even a bent portion of the front chainring. Depending on the damage it can behave “normally” under a low load, but eject the chain under a higher torque load.

Comment: Or too much play in the bottom bracket, worn chain and/or rings, poorly adjusted FD.

Comment: @Carel if the chain comes off when not being shifted, derailleur adjustment is probably not the cause.